# Android Studio - Kotlin: get/setPaintFlags not found

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to use `paintFlags` in my code. The `getPaintFlags` and `setPaintFlags` are red indicating there are not found. I have the correct import: `import android.graphics.Paint`.

The code I have is:

```
title.setPaintFlags(title.getPaintFlags() or Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG)
```

I have also tried:

```
title.paintFlags = title.paintFlags or Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG.inv()
```

The `title`is a TextView. I am using Kotlin.

Comment: are you sure I did it this way
signup_text.paintFlags = signup_text.paintFlags or Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG

Comment: @MRamzan Yeah, it just doesn't work. I'm in process of reinstalling Android Studio, and SDKs, so I'll update if that fixes it. If not, I'm just going to leave it out. It's only for a prototype.

Comment: make sure title is `TextView` not Fragment/Activity title

Comment: @hakim Yup, it's still not working.
        `val title : TextView = findViewById<View>(R.id.title) as TextView` //
        `title.setpaintFlags(title.getpaintFlags() or Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG)`

Comment: Not part of your problem, I think, but you are casting the result of `findViewById` three times when you only need to do it once like: `val title = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.title)`

Comment: Then use `title.paintFlags = title.paintFlags or Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG`

Comment: @Tenfour04 Thank you! That worked. The original  `title.setpaintFlags(title.getpaintFlags() or Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG)` doesn't work, I think I just had the wrong coding, even though I thought I tried that before. 

The casting, if I have only one or three, doesn't seem to affect it. 

Thank you. It was wrecking my head. 

If you want to copy and paste your comment as an answer, I will select it as the answer. Thanks.